# While I'm loading data in JupyterLab I,m getting an Error: "FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab, errno

I just bumped with and error that I never had the code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.read_csv('Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1')
```

I confirmed several times the path and it is correct. the error message is the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-f31adf5ab280> in <module>
----> 1 data=pd.read_csv('Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1 does not exist: 'Users\\ergar\\Desktop\\ML-mini_bootcamp\\W1'
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve it? Thank you in advance for your time in clarifying this issue.

Comment: You have not provided the correct path to the file.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm voting to close this a typo for forgetting the `r` (raw) in front of the path with Windows OS  backslashes. `pd.read_csv(r'Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are giving a relative path to the Py interpreter.
Relative paths are paths that do not start at the root of the filesystem - instead, as the name suggests, they are resolved relative to the location from which you call your program (in this case your notebook).

There are two ways you can solve this.

**Option one** is to use an **absolute path** - for Windows, start at C:\ or another appropriate drive letter - in your case, that would be

```
'C:\Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1.csv'
```

**Option two** is to place your file in the same folder as your notebook and then use a relative path:
`pd.read_csv('W1.csv')`

Note that you can create subfolders and organize your files that way - for instance you could create a datasets subfolder and then use `pd.read_csv(r'datasets\W1.csv')`

Also, remember to use **r'path\to\file'** (raw python strings) for Windows-style paths as '\' is a special character used for tings like new lines and tabs and could be misinterpreted when parsed as a non-raw string.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was right also, but my question is why is this happening? since I always copied the path from JupyterLab and worked just fine, now y have to copy the path from the folder (making non sense to work on JupyterLab) and adding the r at the start, how can I assure to work as I used to? By the way, this is a file that I upload many times simply coding: `data=pd.read_csv('Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1.csv')`

Comment: Well, the path like you wrote it is what is called a relative path (it doesn't start at the root of the filesystem). Meaning, if your notebook or lab server is running from, let's say C:\, it can find the path because there is a C:\Users\... - and if you are positioned somewhere else, it can't find the file.

Imagine I tell you to go to Python street. If there is no Python street in your town you'll tell me there is no such street in your town. But if I tell you "Go to the city of Pandas, Python street", you'll know where to look for it. :)

Comment: Thanks agian, but to avoid that issue with relative path I have in the same folder the notebook and the dataset. Is that enough? Cause I've working that way and this is the first time I got that error.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fully cover what you were asking. I would appreciate it if you would mark it as an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, also assuming the name of your CSV file is `W1`:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm coding in Windows/JupyterLab why now I have to write  + 'r' at the start + The full path (from the actual folder)? I've been copying the path from JupyterLab and worked just fine, what should I do to avoid this and work directly on JupyterLab as I used to?

Answer (score 0):

You must mention file extension, for example if yor file is `.csv` use:

```
data=pd.read_csv('Users\ergar\Desktop\ML-mini_bootcamp\W1.csv')
```